# Prominent top app bar using jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to create and add gestures on top app bar some thing similar to below screenshot using jetpack compose:

[image]

I am able to create collapsible top bar using the below android docs link:
[documentation link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary) but not able to do gestures to expand and collapse along with change in layout using compose. Below is the code I have tried for collapsible toolbar.

```
val toolbarHeight = 48.dp
val toolbarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { toolbarHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }
// our offset to collapse toolbar
val toolbarOffsetHeightPx =

    remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
// now, let's create connection to the nested scroll system and listen to the scroll
// happening inside child LazyColumn
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            // try to consume before LazyColumn to collapse toolbar if needed, hence pre-scroll
            val delta = available.y
            val newOffset = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
            toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value = newOffset.coerceIn(-toolbarHeightPx, 0f)
            // here's the catch: let's pretend we consumed 0 in any case, since we want
            // LazyColumn to scroll anyway for good UX
            // We're basically watching scroll without taking it
            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
```

And below is the gesture link which I want to implement in topbvar
[topbar gesture video](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/8353d18665c17cb7c8aeb02d9cc0e0f64b9e212ee24510e388c2a5f52ea0c6d174833ebdc36f10af7ea51d59098d7996fc843408e84d866b74dc479a6d90bb9d)

Please help me with the links. Thanks!

Comment: Please add code with your current state and explain more clearly what do you wanna get at the end. From your picture it's not clear, do you have the first one and need to get the second one? What gestures do you need to add? It's unclear to me

Comment: Apologies! Please check the edits

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to implement collapsing toolbar like below where the title will animate based on collapsing state this code reference might help you. You need to build a custom layout for it.

[image: CollapsingToolbar]

```
@Composable
fun CollapsingTopBar(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
collapseFactor: Float = 1f, // A value from (0-1) where 0 means fully expanded
content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
val map = mutableMapOf<Placeable, Int>()
Layout(
    modifier = modifier,
    content = content
) { measurables, constraints ->
    map.clear()
    val placeables = mutableListOf<Placeable>()
    measurables.map { measurable ->
        when (measurable.layoutId) {
            BACK_ID -> measurable.measure(constraints)
            SHARE_ID -> measurable.measure(constraints)
            TITLE_ID -> 
   measurable.measure(Constraints.fixedWidth(constraints.maxWidth 
   - (collapseFactor * (placeables.first().width * 2)).toInt()))
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Id Not found")
        }.also { placeable ->
            map[placeable] = measurable.layoutId as Int
            placeables.add(placeable)
        }
    }

    // Set the size of the layout as big as it can
    layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
        placeables.forEach { placeable ->
            when (map[placeable]) {
                BACK_ID -> placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                SHARE_ID -> placeable.run {
                    placeRelative(constraints.maxWidth - width, 0)
                }
                TITLE_ID -> placeable.run {
                    val widthOffset = (placeables[0].width * collapseFactor).roundToInt()
                    val heightOffset = (placeables.first().height - placeable.height) / 2
                    placeRelative(
                        widthOffset,
                        if (collapseFactor == 1f) heightOffset else constraints.maxHeight - height
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

object CollapsingTopBar {
   const val BACK_ID = 1001
   const val SHARE_ID = 1002
   const val TITLE_ID = 1003
   const val COLLAPSE_FACTOR = 0.6f
}


@Composable
fun TopBar(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
currentHeight: Int,
title: String,
onBack: () -> Unit,
shareShow: () -> Unit
) {

Box(
    modifier = modifier.height(currentHeight.dp)
) {
    CollapsingTopBar(
        collapseFactor = // calculate collapseFactor based on max and min height of the toolbar,
        modifier = Modifier
            .statusBarsPadding()
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .layoutId(CollapsingTopBar.BACK_ID)
                .clickable { onBack() }
                .padding(16.dp),
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
            tint = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.text_back)
        )
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .layoutId(CollapsingTopBar.SHARE_ID)
                .clickable { }
                .padding(16.dp),
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Share,
            tint = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.title_share)
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId(CollapsingTopBar.TITLE_ID)
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            text = title,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary),
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
    }
}
}
```

[Sample reference from Google](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetsnack)

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate more on this as I am new to kotlin and jetpack. Also could you provide link to this code if available.

Comment: Added more code on the implementation and a sample from google as reference. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for adding up… is it not possible to use nestedscroll modifier

Comment: I am not sure about that. I have implemented with `ScrollState` like the sample project.